# SDL_image entry point SDL_acosf not found in SDL2_image.dll

Tags: sdl2, visual-studio, dll

I tried using SDL2_image (2.0.3) with SDL2 (2.0.7) to load png files,
but when I start the application I get

```
SDL_image entry point SDL_acosf not found in SDL2_image.dll
```

This even happens when I just include SDL_image.h without actually using any of it`s functionality.

I`m using x86 versions of both libraries. Dlls are in SysWOW64.
Compiling with VS 2017.

What am I missing?

Update: 
This happens when I link against SDL2_image.lib. I don't even need to include SDL_image.h.
Also SDL_acosf doesn't seem to exist in SDL2 or SDL2_image.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it. Apparently I missed the release of SDL2 2.0.8 which has SDL_acosf.

Comment: Got the same problem even with the latest releases of SDL2 and SDL2_image (using SDL2 2.0.8 btw). Figured out what's wrong?

Comment: I can`t really say. It now works for me with SDL2 2.0.8 and SDL_image 2.0.3. SDL_acosf is declared in SDL_stdin.h.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem. It was solved by copying the .dll files from SDL2 and SDL2_image into system32 (and the x86 versions into SysWOW64.)